# How to embed highcharter in rmarkdown to share (not a loop)

Tags: r-markdown, r-highcharter

I cannot get two simple highcharter charts in an Rmarkdown file I want to share. It works fine and renders in my PC or Mac, but when I share the file, people only see text.

They are not part of a loop, as mentioned in few articles. They are just two charts. For the reproducible example, I literally just opened a new rmarkdown doc and selected html. I replaced the "summary table" of cars with highcharter code. I even tried htmltools::tagList(chart1, chart2) and it does not work.

I am supplying the code. If you please show me how to do it with one chart, I can do it with the second.
Thank you.

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---
```

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
````

````
```{r echo=FALSE}
library(magrittr)
library(highcharter)
highchart() %>%
    hc_add_series(cars, type = "scatter", hcaes(speed, dist))
````

I apologize if the tick marks hide the code background, but the three chunks are wrapped with the three tickmarks at the beginning and end of each chunk.

Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the code below produces the file below the code. I now have an entire .html file that has the highchart self contained in the file.

```
---
output:
 html_document:
   self_contained: yes
   mode: selfcontained
---
```

```
{r echo=FALSE}
library(magrittr)
library(highcharter)
highchart() %>%
hc_add_series(cars, type = "scatter", hcaes(speed, dist))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Daniel! It did not work. Same output: Just an rmarkdown doc with text, but no highcharter graph is in the doc. So, if I email the test_file.html to me or try to open it in different browsers, it does not appear, only locally in my pc. Question for you: taking the same code I showed you and adding your suggestion, are you able to share that file (through email for example), click on it and see the highcharter? If so, can you post your complete code?. Remember that it **must** be interactive, not a static plot.

Comment: yes, I updated my answer, with the file I rendered in Rmarkdown that has the chart inside the HTML file. let me know

Comment: Hi Daniel! I get the same file, but that's because it is rendered using local dependencies. The part you highlight shows the path to the file in your PC, where you choose to store it. The issue is **when you share this file, for example, in an email, the interactive chart does not show, only text**. I tried your code, and it shows nicely in my viewer/rstudio or even if I go to my desktop where I saved the html, but try emailing yourself this file as an attachment, let's say, using gmail. When received, try opening it and see if the highcharter is there. Thank you Daniel.

Comment: Will, The email on my laptop worked(plot showed up), but not on my iPhone the plot was not visible and I only got the text